# Scrolling Issues in IOS

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, contentsize

Scroll view did not set content size if I set it using a *dynamic variable* i.e.

```
scrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(320,scrollView.frame.origin.y+120);
```

the scroll view size remains same after calling above method.

But if I set it using a number (integer or float) it gets changed but it gives a very strange effect on scrolling. Picture of effect is attached.

```
scrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(320,1000);
```

This is not allowing me to post image anyways a strange effect appears.

How I can get rid of it?

Please tell Whats going wrong or what I am missing?

Now i have got rannking upto 11 the image for effect is given here.

Before Increasing Content Size:
[image]

After Increasing Content Size on Scrolling follwing effect appears:
[image]

Comment: try using a macro and test!!

Comment: what do u exactly want?? do u want to set the "content size" or "scrollView size" ?

Comment: i want it scroll even i add a new content what is better in your opinion for this case?

Comment: image for issue are now posted in the question please see and let me know if this can be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Select the Scroll View and view its Size Inspector window. Observe that its size is 320 , 713 points (in my case). If you do not see the same
size as what I have, this is a good time to adjust the size so that it is the same as mine. You will
need to use this value in your code

```
(void)viewDidLoad {
scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460);
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 713)];
 [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Comment: i want to a cell dynamically not a single time but every time for long tap and want to increase the height of scrollview which definately can not be set in viewDidLoad.

Comment: image for issue are now posted in the question please see and let me know if this can be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should use frame.height to achieve your goal

the content size must be greater then frame size of scroll view for scroll

and you are using y origin of scroll view so may be that's the problem.

```
scrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(320,scrollView.frame.size.height+120);
```

Comment: i use the height property it does not scrolls but if it does it generates a very occurred effect with a transparent layer over the scrollview while scrolling. I want to get rid of that.

Comment: image for issue are now posted in the question please see and let me know if this can be resolved.

Comment: can you send me code ? on my email kharwar.abhishek9@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
scrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(320,scrollView.frame.origin.y+120);
```

You are setting the scroll view's contentsize's height to `scrollView.frame.origin.y+120`.
Means, if your scroll view's frame is x=40, y=40, width = 500, height = 500. Then the scrollView.frame.origin.y+120 will be equal to 40 + 120 = 160. Which is less than your scrollview's height. So your scroll view won't scroll to up or down.

In the second line:

```
scrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(320,1000);
```

You are scroll view's content size's height to 1000. That is greater than the scroll view's height so it'll scroll to up and down.

Comment: it does scrolls in this case but a transparent layer scroll along with the scroll view which is a bad effect i want to get rid of that. Moreover if i set scrollview.contentsize=CGSizeMake(320,scrollview.frame.size.heiht+120) it also causes nothing to change.       My major concern is to remove that bad transparent scrolling effect

Comment: image for issue are now posted in the question please see and let me know if this can be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Finally.......

The issue was scroll view increases width of scroll view indicator which shows on the screnn while scrolling. You have two options to get rid of this.

1. Disable vertical or horizotnal indicators which one causing problem, but this may cause some problem with scroll view content size in my case it caused a problem last cell was not being viewed.

2.Let it appear but make it out of screen by the following code snippet.

```
    [myScrollView setScrollIndicatorInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, 0, 320.0)];
```

this is working perfectly but scroll indicator is gone out of screen.